# Add button on Sharepoint calendar condition

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, new-item

Looking to disable the new item function on a SharePoint calendar or prevent this from being saved if the start time/date field in the item is less than 24 hours of the current date/time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list validation for this.

Go to the calendar List Settings > Validation and add this formula (`Start Time` being the default calendar column): `=IF([Start Time]>=TODAY()+1;TRUE;FALSE)`.

Then add the custom error message you want to display.

Depending on your site's regional setting, you might have to replace the semicolon `;` with a comma `,`.